# Does the Linux version of Node.js come bundled with libv8?

Tags: debian, package-management, node.js

I'm a bit confused as to how Node.js gets access to libv8.

I downloaded the 64-bit "Linux Binaries (.tar.xz)" for version 6.5.0 of Node.js and extracted them to `/opt` on my Debian Linux machine.  When I run `node -e "console.log(process.versions.v8)"`, I get `5.1.281.81`, which *is* the recent version of V8 I would expect to see running with Node 6.5.0.  However, when I look at Synaptic Package Manager in Debian, its `nodejs` package has a dependency on the `libv8-3.14.5` package; a much older version of V8.

So which is it - does Node use the installed libv8 (the package manager indicates that 3.14.5 is installed on my machine) or does V8 come bundled with Node.js?  Is it compiled into the `node` binary?  If so, why does the package manager have the `libv8` dependency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you download Node.js from [the download site](https://nodejs.org/en/), the binary you get is statically linked against libv8 5.1.281.81. There are a number of ways to verify this:

- look for `libv8` in the binary:

  ```
  strings bin/node | less -plibv8
  ```

  (this will lead you to the "5.1.281.81" string in the binary)
- list the symbols in the binary and unmangle them:

  ```
  nm bin/node | c++filt | less -pv8::
  ```

  (the `v8::` symbols come from libv8).

The archive you downloaded doesn't use Debian's packaging system, so the package manager's dependencies don't come into consideration. If you didn't install the `libv8-3.14.5` package explicitly, presumably some other package installed on your system depends on it. If nothing actually needs it, you can remove `libv8-3.14.5` and you'll see that the `node` binary in `/opt` works fine without it.

In any case, even with a packaged version of Node.js you wouldn't necessarily see a dependency on libv8, because [Node.js includes the source of the V8 engine](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/deps/v8); it's not a separate library (at least not for Node.js).

(To run the above commands, you'll need to install the `binutils` package for `nm` and `c++filt`.)

Comment: So the version of Node.js installed by the Debian repos *isn't* statically linked against libv8?

Comment: The packaged version of Node.js is statically linked against V8 too. In fact, Node.js [includes the source code of the V8 engine](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/deps/v8), it isn't an external dependency (build or runtime).

Comment: Interesting... checking it now, they've removed that libv8 dependency in sid.  It was only still there in jessie.

Comment: Indeed, the change happened with the [packaging of version 4](https://tracker.debian.org/news/711967): "Build using embedded cares, embedded v8, because Node.js is using patched versions of them and no longer allow building with shared system libraries of those."